# internet disconnected while installing hadoop 3.1.3 on 19.10 missing depenedcies

Tags: package-management, apache2, ubuntu-core, 19.10

I had to install Hadoop on ubuntu 19.10 I had started the installation     after some time it started downloading packages etc and connecting things from internet. I had left my laptop.

I went to some work in some other building in department.
    Later I came back there was some wifi dysconnectivity problem. Due to which installation had probably hanged or broken in between

.
I was compiling it from sources
https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html
    I want to know how to restart the hadoop installation from the part where it broke.
    I am pasting the error messages
which I saw on terminal

```
debian@osboxes:~/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.3-src$ sudo ./start-build-env.sh 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.29kB
Step 1/36 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
xenial: Pulling from library/ubuntu
e80174c8b43b: Pull complete 
d1072db285cc: Pull complete 
858453671e67: Pull complete 
3d07b1124f98: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bb5b48c7750a6a8775c74bcb601f7e5399135d0a06de004d000e05fd25c1a71c
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:xenial
 ---> 5f2bf26e3524
Step 2/36 : WORKDIR /root
 ---> Running in 72cf4c8b1db1
Removing intermediate container 72cf4c8b1db1
 ---> 81c9b83ca600
Step 3/36 : RUN echo APT::Install-Recommends "0"\; > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10disableextras
 ---> Running in 3cd8b4905e58
Removing intermediate container 3cd8b4905e58
 ---> c36ec6e01627
Step 4/36 : RUN echo APT::Install-Suggests "0"\; >>  /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10disableextras
 ---> Running in 904d844e6670
Removing intermediate container 904d844e6670
 ---> 0b92e04c7c4b
Step 5/36 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Running in e6112f0d3364
Removing intermediate container e6112f0d3364
 ---> 5516fb2c3e3e
Step 6/36 : ENV DEBCONF_TERSE true
 ---> Running in 38545d5b8232
Removing intermediate container 38545d5b8232
 ---> fd4ac783d7c5
Step 7/36 : RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -q install -y     apt-utils     build-essential     bzip2     curl     doxygen     fuse     g++     gcc     git     gnupg-agent     libbz2-dev     libcurl4-openssl-dev     libfuse-dev     libprotobuf-dev     libprotoc-dev     libsnappy-dev     libssl-dev     libtool     libzstd1-dev     locales     make     pinentry-curses     pkg-config     python     python2.7     python-pip     python-pkg-resources     python-setuptools     python-wheel     rsync     software-properties-common     snappy     sudo     zlib1g-dev
 ---> Running in fb21dae2829d
Step 8/36 : RUN apt-get -q install -y openjdk-8-jdk
 ---> Running in e88bcf7743e2
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0
  libflac8 libgif7 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libjson-c2 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libpcsclite1 libpulse0 libsndfile1 libwrap0
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  default-jre libasound2-plugins alsa-utils gvfs pcscd pulseaudio
  openjdk-8-demo openjdk-8-source visualvm icedtea-8-plugin libnss-mdns
  fonts-dejavu-extra fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho
  fonts-wqy-microhei fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-indic
Recommended packages:
  libgtk2.0-bin tcpd libxt-dev fonts-dejavu-extra
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java java-common libasound2 libasound2-data libasyncns0
  libflac8 libgif7 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libjson-c2 libnspr4 libnss3
  libnss3-nssdb libpcsclite1 libpulse0 libsndfile1 libwrap0 openjdk-8-jdk
  openjdk-8-jdk-headless openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 41.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 156 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libjson-c2 amd64 0.11-4ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libasyncns0 amd64 0.8-5build1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libwrap0 amd64 7.6.q-25
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 java-common all 0.56ubuntu2
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnspr4 amd64 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnspr4 amd64 2:4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6
Err:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3-nssdb all 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpcsclite1 amd64 1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1
Err:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libnss3 amd64 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpcsclite1 amd64 1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1 [21.4 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [27.1 MB]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libpcsclite1 amd64 1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20160321ubuntu1 [12.5 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [27.1 MB]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20160321ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libasound2-data all 1.1.0-0ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libasound2 amd64 1.1.0-0ubuntu1 [350 kB]
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libasound2 amd64 1.1.0-0ubuntu1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libflac8 amd64 1.3.1-4 [210 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgif7 amd64 5.1.4-0.3~16.04.1 [30.5 kB]
Err:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libflac8 amd64 1.3.1-4
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libgif7 amd64 5.1.4-0.3~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-common all 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 [123 kB]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libgif7 amd64 5.1.4-0.3~16.04.1 [30.5 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-0 amd64 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2 [1775 kB]
Err:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-common all 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libgif7 amd64 5.1.4-0.3~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgtk2.0-0 amd64 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.25-10ubuntu0.16.04.2 [139 kB]
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.25-10ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libpulse0 amd64 1:8.0-0ubuntu3.10
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [68.8 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.25-10ubuntu0.16.04.2 [139 kB]
Err:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Err:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libsndfile1 amd64 1.0.25-10ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [8212 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [1607 kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [68.8 kB]
Err:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Ign:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
Err:19 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [8212 kB]
Err:20 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk-headless amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1 [1607 kB]
Err:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 openjdk-8-jdk amd64 8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
Fetched 113 kB in 2min 53s (650 B/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/json-c/libjson-c2_0.11-4ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libasyncns/libasyncns0_0.8-5build1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tcp-wrappers/libwrap0_7.6.q-25_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/j/java-common/java-common_0.56ubuntu2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nspr/libnspr4_4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3-nssdb_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/nss/libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.6_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

    E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What should I do to restart it from point where thing broke.
I followed instructions in BUILDING.txt file from the downloaded

```
/home/debian/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.3-src
```

Some how due to broken connections what should I do is not mentioned?
If any one wants to see full error messages they can see this https://pastebin.com/rRmUDKcn
Let me know what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your JDK and re-install it.

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre
```

It will work. Let me know if any problem occurs.